# Why does stargazer produce different dependent variable labels for these two models?

Tags: r, stargazer

I am wondering if someone could tell me *why* stargazer producers different dependent variable labels for the two models below:

```
j <- "hp"
i <- "cyl"

lm1 <- lm(paste(j, "~", i), mtcars)
stargazer(lm1, header = FALSE, type = "text")
```

produces dependent variable *j*

whereas:

```
model <- paste(j, "~", i)
lm2 <- lm(model, mtcars)
stargazer(lm2, header = FALSE, type = "text")
```

produces the correct dependent variable *hp*

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the non-standard evaluation. Even if you try `as.formula(paste(j, "~", i))` within variable call you get `j`.

Comment: My favorite function for this purpose is `reformulate`: `reformulate(i, response=j)` will construct the formula for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `stargazer` picks the dependent variable labels from the `call` attribute of the model, so when line 51 from the internal code (https://github.com/cran/stargazer/blob/master/R/stargazer-internal.R) is executed, it reads `j` instead of `hp`

You can see that if you copy the `call` atribute from lm2 to lm1 now you get it:

```
lm1$call <- lm2$call
stargazer(lm1, header = FALSE, type = "text")
```